# Where to find the data from add to cart button when clicked using MarketPress in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if someone could guide me through the MarketPress plugin for Wordpress. I'm about to determine whether the item or the products is still available or out of stock. I don't know where to find the table where the data is being inserted. In the first place, I don't know where to locate the specific method or function that inserts the purchase details when I click the add to cart button. Please help. :(